# Button click to previous page asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I am know some .Net basic but i need to do more advanced thing and I am stuck.
I have empClientProfile.aspx page access to this page possible from different places (from list of clients, direct  from menu  and other.) I want to put  button by pressing  which  it  will redirect user on exact same page as he/she was before. For example if client  doing  select from agencies it should forward to exact same page with that select. If this page was accessed from main menu  it  should forward to home menu.

Using `PostBackURL` doesn't work here because as I said page can be reached from different  pages.

Any Ideas how to do it?

Comment: I don't know how . Im kind of new with .Net cannot do advenced things

Comment: Please check http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91641/Navigate-to-Previous-Page-in-ASP-NET

Comment: The solution will take you to previous page. **But remember that the previous page can be the same page**.

Comment: yes that's the problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following button code in your HTML

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.history.back()" />
```

## UPDATE

Try these files and test it out...

filename: page1.htm

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>page 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    PAGE 1<br />
    <a href="page2.htm">Jump to page 2</a><br />
    <a href="page3.htm">Jump to page 3</a><br />
  </body>
</html>
```

filename: page2.htm

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>page 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    PAGE 2<br />
    <a href="page3.htm">Jump to page 3</a><br />
    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.history.back()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

filename: page3.htm

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>page 3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    PAGE 3<br />
    <a href="page1.htm">Jump to page 1</a><br />
    <input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.history.back()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so it should be `<asp:Button ID="btn_topriviousScreen" runat="server" 
        Text="Back" onclick="window.history.back()" />`

Comment: throws error `Error 554 'ASP.employee_empclientprofile_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'window' and no extension method 'window' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.employee_empclientprofile_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Moonbeam\Desktop\SQL FB\New folder (2)\New folder (2)\CSFP Front-End\Employee\empClientProfile.aspx 720 `

Comment: No the code i gave you was CLIENTSIDE CODE, it goes in the HTML.  when you use "ASP:Button" That is a serverside button

Comment: It will work on ANY browser on ANY Page, it will return the user the PREVIOUS Page as found from in HISTORY object. place it in your HTML dont use "ASP:Button" or "Runat='Server'" only pure HTML. and it will return the user to the previous page.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can use session to do it based on user action

```
switch(action)
{
case 1:
   postbackurl = Session[a].toString();
case 2:
   postbackurl = Session[b].toString();
default:
   break;

}
```

Comment: should i post it in button click event ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Request.UrlReferrer ?